# Why am I getting Null in the console first and then later I get the value (react.js)

Tags: reactjs

Should be getting the values for latitude and longitude but for some reason I am getting the initial state which is "null" and then in the same time getting another response with the data in the console.

[image: This is what the console.log looks like when I refresh the page]

As seen in the image, it first returns that it is null and then later (without refreshing or anything) returns the values. **BELOW IS MY CODE**

This is where I get my value for coords (from a react library)

```
//Getting geolocation
const {coords, isGeolocationAvailable , isGeolocationEnabled} = useGeolocated({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    },
    userDecisionTimeout: 5000,
})

//Setting Latitude and Longitude states
useEffect (() => {
    if (coords) {
       setLatitiude(coords.latitude)
       setLongitude(coords.longitude) 
    }
}, [coords]);

//Fetch data from API
useEffect (() => {
    console.log(`Latitude = ${latitude} and Longitude = ${longitude}`)
    //Function to call API
    const weatherForecast = async () => {
        await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((res) => {
        setWeatherDetails(res.data)
    })
    } 

    if(latitude !== null & longitude !== null) {
        weatherForecast()
    } else {
        console.log("Error getting data")
    }
   
 }, [latitude , longitude]);
```

When I first npm start the frontend it works as should but the moment i refresh this is what happens. Any idea what is going on and why this looks like it is re rendering three times to get the result. As a result of that behaviour my API isn't getting the needed data and returning an error.

Comment: From where are you getting the value of `coords`?

Comment: @SanketShah Edited it in the question now but basically it is a react library which I am sure is returning info all the time as i have tested it by console.log it always returns the data needed

Comment: You are logging the coords before loading the data. How do you expect it to have value?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Can you clarify what you mean ? Because that code is at the very top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `null` value for the first time because you're logging it before the `coords` data is even loaded.

try this instead

```
//Getting geolocation
const {coords, isGeolocationAvailable , isGeolocationEnabled} = useGeolocated({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    },
    userDecisionTimeout: 5000,
})

//Setting Latitude and Longitude states
useEffect (() => {
    if (coords) {
       setLatitiude(coords.latitude)
       setLongitude(coords.longitude) 
    }
}, [coords]);

//Function to call API
const weatherForecast = async () => {
   await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
     .then((res) => {
       setWeatherDetails(res.data)
     }).catch(() => {
       console.log("Error getting data")
     })
} 

//Fetch data from API
useEffect (() => {
    if(latitude !== null && longitude !== null){ 
     console.log(`Latitude = ${latitude} and Longitude = ${longitude}`)
        weatherForecast()
    }
   
 }, [latitude , longitude]);
```

Comment: Just tried that , in that case the weatherForecast() function is not running although in the console it show me the values of long and lat

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the value of both `latitude` and `longitude`? @HadiZouhbi

Comment: Yes, in the console.log it says latitude = 5.9698224  and longitude = -1.7831068

Comment: Still just showing the longitude and latitude but never actually running the function

Comment: How are you so sure that the function is not running. Are you performing any action after setting the weather details? Because according to me if the values of `latitude` and `longitude` are getting printed then the function should get called. There might be some error with your `API_ENDPOINT` or `API_KEY`

Comment: Working now, sorry it was my mistake, I forgot to console.log it , Silly mistake I know haha thank you so much ! Code works as expected now !

Answer (score 1):

A useEffect is called after the component has rendered. So the first time, latitude and longitude (and probably cords are null).

The second time I would guess cords exists and sets long and lat. Which triggers a re-render since your second useEffect has them in its dependency. array

And after the third render long and lat are set.

In react it is very common to have multiple re-renders.

Comment: But it only sends a request once to the API when the values of Latitude and Longitude are null so i am getting a failed request. It does not attempt to do the request to the API again when they aren't null , how do I fix that

Comment: By the way forgot to add , that behaviour is happening only after I refresh the page but when I npm start the project initially it does not happen

Comment: I would have coded it like this:

useEffect (() => {
   if (!latitude || !longitude) return;

    const weatherForecast = async () => {
        await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((res) => {
        setWeatherDetails(res.data)
    })
    } 

     weatherForecast()
    
 }, [latitude , longitude]);

Comment: there is an error in your code at the weatherForecast() part , did you mean to pass that as dependency?

Comment: Im not sure what went wrong, I hope you understand the intention of the code.
You wrote that you get a failed request. Since you check for long and lat, are API_ENDPOINT or API_KEY not loaded?

Comment: API_ENDPOINT and API_KEY are 100% loaded , I know from the response of the error it shows me that lat and lon are null

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to reason out for the two renderings(which actually should be one) before you actually get the values: React StrictMode which by default is enabled, will cause the useEffect to run twice but only in development mode regardless of the dependencies after the INITIAL rendering to ensure that you are aware of all the possible side effects and that the cleanup handlers work as expected. You can find more on it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state).